# Difference between F5, Ctrl + F5 and click on refresh button?

Tags: browser, refresh, webbrowser-control, browser-refresh

I have often experienced while developing my web applications that pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or refresh doesn't produce or refresh the proper result. But when we hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> it generates the correct result. What is the basic difference between simple <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>?

I have often also experienced that pressing simple <kbd>F5</kbd> and pressing the <kbd>Refresh</kbd> button in the browser also generate different results.

What is the basic difference among all these requests?

Comment: and also what if we press enter in address bar of browser since I am getting different load times for F5, ctrl+F5, ctrl+R and (pressing enter in address bar), viewing in chrome browser's "Network" tab (ctrl+shift+i)

Comment: Well, XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1854/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> Reloads the current page, ignoring cached content and generating the expected result.

Comment: IMO CTRL +F5 displays new content only. It doesn't clear the cache it bypasses the cache https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Answer (score 46):

I did small research regarding this topic and found different behavior for the browsers:

[image]

See my blog post "[Behind refresh button](https://web.archive.org/web/20131026195830/http://podlipensky.com/2012/03/behind-refresh-button/)" for more details.

Comment: The blog post link changed to http://podlipensky.com/2012/03/behind-refresh-button/

Comment: The blog post can still be found via https://web.archive.org/web/20131026195830/http://podlipensky.com/2012/03/behind-refresh-button/

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>F5</kbd> and the refresh button will look at your browser cache before asking the server for content.

<kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd> forces a load from the server.

You can set [content expiration headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) and/or [meta tags](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html) to ensure the browser doesn't cache anything (perhaps something you can do only for the development environment).

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>F5</kbd> triggers a standard reload.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> triggers a *forced* reload. This causes the browser to re-download the page from the web server, ensuring that it always has the latest copy.

Unlike with <kbd>F5</kbd>, a forced reload does not display a cached copy of the page.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>F5</kbd> is a standard page reload.

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> refreshes the page by clearing the cached content of the page.

Having the cursor in the address field and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will also do the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: No you are wrong. "Having cursor in the address field
 and pressing ENTER will also do" F5 and not CTRL+F5 in GOOGLE CHROME. I have verified this using 'Developer Console' in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F5</kbd> reloads the page from server, but it uses the browser's cache for page elements like scripts, image, CSS stylesheets, etc, etc. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, reloads the page from the server and also reloads its contents from server and doesn't use local cache at all.

So by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> on, say, the Yahoo homepage, it just reloads the main HTML frame and then loads all other elements like images from its cache. If a new element was added or changed then it gets it from the server. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> reloads everything from the server.