# CodeIgniter Responsive HTML and CSS and JS

Tags: codeigniter, web, responsive

how do i make a responsible website using CodeIgniter?

I am currently working on a website that is built by CI and i have tried changing the css in the assets file, and then i tried to inspect the page for God knows how many times, but it didn't change a thing.

I have made a new css file in which all the @media min-width is 502px
but still, didn't make any change

Comment: Unless you specifically set no-cache headers, your browser may be caching the CSS. First try setting no-cache headers, then turn off page caching in your browser, then try again.

Comment: Also, look around here or Google for "cache busting", and implement it in your site. It's one of the essentials for modern websites.

Comment: While you are in development mode - this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589760/difference-between-f5-ctrl-f5-and-click-or-refresh-button. This used to drive me crazy as well :)

Comment: Your question is not specific enough - it can basically be everything. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

use the below tag in your view pages
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"

Comment: should i change the device-width to my desired size?

Comment: no..use tag in head part 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">